# How do I get Genesect in ORAS or XY other than a wonder card?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Is Genesect strictly obtainable through events in Pokémon ORAS and XY?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Genesect is unobtainable through normal play in XY and ORAS. You'll have to wait for an event that distributes it. Incidentally, there is going to be a Genesect event from November 1 to November 24, via codes given at Gamestop.

Comment: Oh ok, that's what I was thinking. Thank you much!

Comment: @KyleDoobs Thanks are nice, but you should take the time to vote up useful answers, and accept the one that helped you most.